# Not able to create session in saucelab real /virtual mobile with selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, appium, saucelabs

Using selenium 4.1.0 with appium latest version 8.0.0 beta.
Getting below exception while launching browser in saucelab real device.

"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Unknown error while proxying appium request, please contact Sauce Labs support, error id is '5f6b32e0-39f0-46e7-b46c-15ff42842f42'
Build info: version: '4.1.0', revision: '87802e897b'
System info: host: 'TOCONAV11X361B', ip: '10.28.104.127', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:automationName=UiAutomator2, browserName=Safari, appium:deviceName=iPhone X, platformName=iOS, appium:platformVersion=13}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: Safari, deviceName: iPhone X, platformName: iOS, platformVersion: 13}}]
Capabilities {}"

Answer (score 3):

There are two things here:

1. Currently Sauce Labs Real Device Cloud (RDC) does not support W3C capabilities, this will be delivered in January 2022, please check the notification banner in the Sauce Labs UI
2. Is is not advised to use the Selenium driver to automate Android Emulators / iOS Simulators / Real devices

The reason for not using Selenium the selenium driver to automate mobile devices is that Selenium can only interact, and thus automate, web based components.
On mobile devices you can for example get:

- permission modals to accept using the location
- native select boxes like the pickerwheel on iOS and the Android modal with all options
- and many more things that are device/platform and not browser specific

All the above mentioned things can **not** be automated with Selenium, but they can be automated with Appium. Appium supports W3C, but adds more mobile specific commands to it so you are able to finish your complete end-2-end flow.

To prevent getting stuck in the future it is highly recommended to use the Appium Driver of your preferred language instead of the Selenium Driver.

Comment: yes i'm using appium driver (java client 7.2.0/7.1.0) for driver instantiation, still not bale to create session.Using code " new AndroidDriver(url, caps);"

Comment: Can you then please file a ticket with Sauce Support so they can help you. Can you then provide all needed info like the caps that you are sending and the url of the instance in Sauce Labs that holds that error?